# Instagram toolbar on top of screen

Tags: kivy, kivymd

here i am trying to create  a simple  Instagram   toolbar on the top of screen, here is my py file :

```
from kivymd.app import  MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.lang import Builder
class HomePage(MDScreen):
    pass
class InstagramApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Window.size =[300,600]
        Builder.load_file("home_page.kv")
        return HomePage()

InstagramApp().run()
```

and corresponding kv file

```
<HomePage>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    # App Bar
    MDBoxLayout:
        padding: '5dp'
        adaptive_height: True

        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'plus'

        MDLabel:
            text: 'Instagram'
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'top'
            font_size: 25


        MDIconButton:
            icon: 'facebook-messenger'
```

but result is this :
[image]

how can i move it  to top size? thanks in advance